# What is the limit for the radical $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm trying to find oblique asmyptotes for the function $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$ and I manage to caclculate that the coefficient for the asymptote when x approaches infinity is 1.

But when i try to find the m-value for my oblique asymptote by taking the limit of:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x=m
$$

I'm stuck.

How do i simplify this expression to find the limit?

I've tried manipulating the radical by converting it to the denominator:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}-x.$$

Or by multiplying both terms with the conjugate:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$$

But in neither case do I know how to take the limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1} \neq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression simplifies to

$${x+1\over\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$$

There are now various ways to proceed.  One is to divide numerator and denominator by $x$, bringing the $x$ in the denominator inside as an $x^2$:

$${x+1\over\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}={1+{1\over x}\over\sqrt{1+{1\over x}+{1\over x^2}}}$$

Do you see where this is going?

**Added later**:  I answered too quickly, without checking how you got to the last expression.  It turns out it's missing a "$+x$" in the denominator: it should have been

$${x+1\over\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$$

so when you do the trick I advised you get

$${x+1\over\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}={1+{1\over x}\over\sqrt{1+{1\over x}+{1\over x^2}}+1}$$

Comment: Yes I believe; 
$$\frac{1+0}{\sqrt{1+0+0}}=1$$ 
right?. But then is my asymptote:

$ax+b=x+1?$ Because that's what i keep coming up with and it's not correct somehow...

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That was my error all along!

Comment: @StrangeBrew, it's often easier to spot the error someone else made than it is to spot your own.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do the difference, divide!

$\lim_{x->\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{x}=1$ very easily

For $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x²}}$

EDIT: It is not over, of course, since the asymptote does not necessarily goes through the origin... You have to make the actual difference between the function and $x+a$. But by using the same strategy, you will find easily the result.

EDIT2: in order to be more complete.

$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x=x\times(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x²}}-1)=\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x²}}+1}$

Whose limit is clearly $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic. By dividing by x don't we lose the b, since it will go to 0 when we take the limit? Isn't this just the 1 i have as my coefficient? I'm trying to follow my textbook which explains finding the oblique asymptote by 

$$ lim_{x->\infty} f(x)-(ax+b)$$ 

Where f(x) goes to 0 when we take the limit. Thus i get the coefficient a by: 

$$ lim_{x->\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}-a $$

But I can't divide by x when I'm trying to figure out b.

Comment: That is the second step that I explained afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x->\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x$$
$$=\lim_{x->\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$$
$$=\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$$
The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits
$$=\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$$
The limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits
The limit of a constant is the constant
$$=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits
$$=\frac{1}{\infty+\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
Use the power law
$$=\frac{1}{\infty+\sqrt{\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}x^2+x+1}} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\infty+\infty} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\infty} + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
$$=0 + \lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
$$=\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
The limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits
The limit of a constant is the constant
The limit of a sum is the sum of the limits
$$=\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2}}}$$
Use the power law
$$=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2}}}$$
Use L'Hopital
$$=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\displaystyle\lim_{x->\infty}1+\frac{1}{2x}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\displaystyle1+\frac12\cdot\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\displaystyle1+\frac12\cdot0}}$$
$$=\color{lightgray}{\boxed{\color{black}{\dfrac{1}{2}}}}$$

Comment: You copied this or what?

Comment: @Infinity It's simple application of simple rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mistake in your last expression. We have 
$$ \sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x = \frac{x^2+x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x} = \frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} $$

Therefore we have $$\lim(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x)= \lim\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}} + 1} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: I honestly don't know why.

Comment: You forgot a bracket or two.  :)

Comment: @SpamIAm, actually there was one too many.  I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to complete to square $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-x=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}-x=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2}-x=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2(1+\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2})}-x=(x+1/2)-x=1/2$$

Comment: That does seem very neat. I'm wondering how you got from step 2 to step 3 and also from step 3 to step 4. Maybe you could direct me to some more general explanation?

Comment: @StrangeBrew I made i mistake It should be Step 2 to Step 4,and Step 4 to Step 3 to Step 5.Anyway I've rewriten $\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}$ from the brackets so it became $\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2(1+\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2}}$ now I've wrote it as $\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2}}$.And the second root $\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2}}$ equal to $1$ since $x$ tends to infinity so $\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2}=0$.

Comment: Okay that explains a bit more. However I still don't understand quite what you've done. The way i calculate it;

$$\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+3/4}=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+\frac{3(x+1/2)^2}{4(x+1/2)^2}}=\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2\frac{3x^2+3x+1/4}{4(x+1/2)^2}}=?$$ Here I don't see the continuation to get to your expression.

Comment: Well $(x+1/2)^2(1+\frac{3}{4(x+1/2)^2})=(x+1/2)^2+\frac{3(x+1/2)^2}{4(x+1/2)^2}$

Comment: Okay, how do you get there?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x = \frac{x^2 + x + 1 - x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} + x} = \frac{x + 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x}.$$
L'Hopital's rule then gives
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} - x = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}.$$